# Using PPP on an Android tablet

Tags: android, protocols, ppp, pppd

I have been looking for a way to use the point to point protocol in an android application, but I didn't succeed. I firstly checked if the module is supported by my tablet kernel, and so, I executed "pppd" with the right parameters after connecting through USB with my PC (adb). The android kernel did recognize the command but it displayed this message :

```
This system lacks kernel support for ppp
```

So I looked for a Java implementation of the point to point protocol and I was surprised that I couldn't find it (apart for an implementation on TINI).
I so have two questions: the first one is if there is any way to use the ppp daemon on android without the need to root it or use the NDK.
The second one is if there is a Java implementation of this protocol.
Thanks for all your help, I really need it.

Comment: You need to compile a custom kernel with ppp driver and supporting modules to go with it, does not exist in Java AFAIK.

Comment: @t0mm13b : I tought about it, but if i want to deploy my app on other devices, I'll need to recompile as well an other custom kernel.

Comment: depends on if that other devices has that ppp compiled into kernel, if its smartphone that has telephony - chances are good it will have that in place! If its tablet without telephony, then yes, you will need to recompile the kernel for that specific device, no two kernels are the same for each and different devices!

Comment: unfortunately, the app is written to be used on Android tablets essentially, so apart from actually developping the ppp protocol is there an other solution...

Comment: Are they all the same tablets? Or by different manufacturers? If they are, then that would imply, rooting each and every tablet in order to recompile the kernels for each specific device...that's about how far it can go, why not go with wifi, wifi tethering even?

Comment: They are all by different manufacturers. Actually, i have to dial-up a modem using a Bluetooth/serial RS232 converter from the tablet. I can send AT commands to the modem and call an internet GateWay wich start a PPP connexion in order to provide access to Internet. So i have to access via Bluetooth not the wifi.